# How to authorize namespace, model-less controllers using CanCanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

What is the correct way to authorize and check abilities for a namespaced, model-less controller using CanCanCan?

After much googling and reading the wiki, I currently have

```
#controllers/namespaces/unattacheds_controller.rb
def Namespaces::UnattachedsController
  authorize_resource class: false
  def create 
    # does some stuff
  end
end

#models/ability.rb
def admin 
  can [:create], :namespaces_unattacheds
end

#view/
<%= if can? :create, :namespaces_unattacheds %>
# show a create form to authorized users
<% end %>
```

This is not correctly authorizing the controller. Admins can see the conditional create form, but are not authorized to post to the create action.

```
post :create, valid_params
Failure/Error: { it { expect( flash ).to have_content "Successfully created" } 
expected to find text "Successfully created"
got: "You are not authorized to access this page."
```

In one example, the wiki suggests creating a separate Ability class for a namespaced controller. https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Admin-Namespace

Is there a simpler way to achieve this? This app uses many namespaced controllers, I don't really want to create an ability class for each one.

Is there correct syntax to refer to the namespaced controller in the Ability class?

```
can [:create], Namespaces::Unattacheds
can [:create], :namespaces_unattacheds
can [:create], namespaces/unattacheds
????
```

Comment: `Namespaces::UnattachedsController` is a class, not a def, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer because this question seems to be getting a reasonable number of visitors. Hope it can help someone.

I received some good suggestions here, that helped me think through my problem. Ultimately I realised that I was fighting against CanCanCan's conventions with what I was trying to achieve.

I swapped to [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit), which allowed me to authorise an object in the controller while referring to a specific policy class. Something like

```
# Admin::UserController
def update
authorize @user, policy_class: Admin::UserPolicy
end

# UserController
def update 
authorize @user, policy_class: UserPolicy
end
```

Combined with strong params defined on the controller, I was able to ensure that only specific attributes could be updated.

This won't work for everyone. For example, this approach would not prevent admins from updating all a user's attributes if they bypass the controller (e.g., via the console). But it worked for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are setting permissions on the `Namespaces::Unattacheds` model, which means your controller doesn't need to do:

```
authorize_resource class: false
```

Your controller does have a model.  Maybe it also inherits from ApplicationController?  (That would be a logical thing to do.)

If you are trying to avoid affecting certain controller methods, use `only`/`except` clauses, as described here:
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions#choosing-actions

I don't think the namespace depth is an issue IF it matches between your model and your controller.  You just need `load_and_authorize_resource` and the proper form in `ability.rb`:

```
can [:create], Namespaces::Unattacheds
```

Comment: Thanks. There are several controllers that refer to the same model - Users. But each controller has different permissions associated. I don't think abilities can therefore be defined for the User. I need a way to define permissions for the controller

Comment: The `can` statements for all controllers should be in the same Ability class.  It should describe the complete set of operations available, based on the model, regardless of what controller is current.  That means you might need statements like `can :create, SomeClass if admin?`.  Thinking of it as controller-centric is anti-pattern for CanCan.

Comment: Using CanCan, how would you authorise only admin to approve/reject a User (an update action), but only User to update their own attributes, without deviating from CRUD controller format?

Comment: Your concern is to allow admins to update ONLY the approval/rejection component and not other attributes? From cancan's perspective, you might model that differently where `ApproveRejectAction` is a separate model that `belongs_to :user`.  Then `can :create, ApproveRejectAction if admin?` and `can :update, User, id: current_user.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the prettiest solution but I managed to achive this by adding

```
skip_authorization_check
before_action { raise CanCan::AccessDenied unless current_user.can?(params[:action].to_sym, ::namespaces_unattacheds) }
```

If you do it like this, you can pass whatever you want from this controller to the ability class.

You need to add the can? method first to be able to use this https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Ability-for-Other-Users