# How do you authorize access to a page dealed by a controller without corresponding model with Cancancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, authorization, spree, cancancan

## The issue

A Spree admin controller without corresponding model, whose access trial redirect to an other page.

The corresponding attempt code:

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    class TutorialsController < Spree::Admin::BaseController
      authorize_resource :class => false

      def index
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And in `app/models/spree/ability_decorator.rb` the following was added:

```
  can :manage, :'tutorial'
  can :manage, :'admin/tutorial'
  can :manage, :'admin_tutorial'
  can :manage, :'spree/admin/tutorial'
  can :manage, :'spree_admin_tutorial'
```

But none of these authorizations will do the trick. Of course adding `can :manage, :all` at this place will make the page reachable as desired, so this is definitely solution close to that which is needed but less permissive that is looked for here. Even using `skip_authorization_check` in the controller won't do the trick, the request will be redirected to `admin/products` with these corresponding initial logs:

```
Started GET "/admin/tutorials" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-04-30 17:11:28 +0200                                                                                                                     
Processing by Spree::Admin::TutorialsController#index as HTML                                                                                                                                 
  Spree::Preference Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "spree/backend_configuration/locale"], ["LIMI
T", 1]]                                                                                                                                                                                       
  ↳ /home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@project/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-a03ecad00a1e/lib/spree_i18n/controller_locale_helper.rb:21                                                    
  Spree::User Load (3.2ms)  SELECT  "spree_users".* FROM "spree_users" WHERE "spree_users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "spree_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "spree_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 
194], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                                                                                                                                                           
  ↳ /home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@project/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98                                                                        
  Spree::Role Load (3.4ms)  SELECT "spree_roles".* FROM "spree_roles" INNER JOIN "spree_role_users" ON "spree_roles"."id" = "spree_role_users"."role_id" WHERE "spree_role_users"."user_id" = 
$1  [["user_id", 194]]                                                                                                                                                                        
  ↳ /home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@project/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98                                                                        
  Spree::Producer Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "spree_producers".* FROM "spree_producers" WHERE "spree_producers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/spree/ability_decorator.rb:123                                                  
Redirected to http://localhost:5000/forbidden                                                                                                                                                 
Completed 302 Found in 80ms (ActiveRecord: 41.4ms)
```

And after a few other redirections, the request lead to the previously stated path.

## Pertaining related resources

- [Adding a Controller without corresponding model while using cancancan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763269/adding-a-controller-without-corresponding-model-while-using-cancancan) proposes a solution which unfortunately didn't work in this case.
- [How to authorize namespace, model-less controllers using CanCanCan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084104/how-to-authorize-namespace-model-less-controllers-using-cancancan) suggest the use of `skip_authorization_check`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need for special ability after all in this case. The `Spree::BaseController` sets the correct permissions to grant the aimed access, unlike `Spree::Admin::BaseController`. To keep the CSS style consistent, an explicit `layout` statement is required.

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    class TutorialsController < Spree::BaseController
      layout 'spree/layouts/admin'
      def index; end
    end
  end
end
```